# Allow access to my angular server

Tags: angular, server

Hi I want to know if it's possible give access to another pc in my network to into in my angular server, for example i want to see my app on my laptop while I'm working on the code from my desktop pc

Comment: I'm usigin angular 6

Comment: So you want to edit the code via your laptop, but the code actually live on the desktop? So you can host the angular app from your desktop? What operating systems are you using on your laptop and desktop?

Comment: have you tried accessing the app using the IP?

Comment: No Im taking a course from udemy, I watch the course in my android, Im doing the practice on my desktop pc, so I would like see the app in real time on my laptop to see the changes, but i put the "localhost:4200" on laptop and didnt work

Comment: If you using node.js , then you got to type *npm start* to fire up the local server in your laptop.

Comment: `localhost:4200` is relative to the computer you are writing the code on. Only the computer you are using can use that address because `localhost` is a special address that is a self reference. You need to get the IP address of that computer via `ip addr show` on linux, `ifconfig | grep inet` on Mac or `ipconfig` on Windows, and let's say it's `192.168.1.2` You use the other device that's also on the local network and type `192.168.1.2:4200` in the address bar

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

First you need to find IP address of the machine you need to access URL from. And make sure both the devices are sharing same WiFi or LAN network.

Now assuming you are running application on port `4200` i.e. `localhost:4200`.

After getting IP address of the machine (Let's assume its `192.168.1.25`) go to your other device and put `192.168.1.25:4200` in browser. You should be able to view your application.